# How to align items to rightmost edge of multi-column span (css grid)

Tags: css, css-grid, css-multicolumn-layout

I'm working with a CSS grid layout with a 20 column span. For ne of my grid items I've specified that it span 5 columns, like so:

```
   .parent-grid {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: repeat(20, 1fr);
   }

   .grid-item-a {
     grid-column: span 5;
   }
```

The content in `.grid-item-a` does not (and should not) fill the entire width of those 5 columns (they have a fixed width of `200px`); I specified 5 columns there to set the distance between it and the content adjacent to it. However, the content in `.grid-item-a` is aligned to the leftmost side of that span. Is there anyway to align it all the way to the right? I've tried using `align-items` and `justify-items` but have had no luck.

Comment: Where's the Html ? and the css code for the `200px`. Put up a  working snippet illustrating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
float : right;
```

or

```
margin-right:0;
```

in your Code.
Hope it Helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need here is `grid-column-end`

Therefore assigning `grid-column-end: 5` should do the job.

More info here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column-end